# Where Can One Find their Deleted Questions Or Answers?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I would like to undelete one of my deleted past questions, but I can't find where they are located..

Where I can see all my deleted questions? (And then undelete)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can only get *recently* deleted questions/answers (those posted within the last 60 days).

Your links would be:

- https://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/3649903 for questions
- https://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-answers/3649903 for answers

where 3649903 is your userid.

These links can be found at the bottom of your questions/answers listings in [your profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=topactivity).

If the posts are too old to be listed anymore and you desperately need that link  you can raise a custom moderator flag on one of your posts and ask a moderator to go looking for that deleted post. Don't use this option frivolous and practice patience as these requests are not considered high-priority by the Moderator team.

Comment: Those links are private to you and will show 404 pages for anyone who isn't.

Comment: Where could I suggest to move that link up, before the list? Would have been way more visible, to me at least.