# Deleted questions not in browser history or wayback machine

Tags: support, deleted-questions, post-ban

I got banned from asking questions on Stack Overflow, definitely deserved.

Now that I think I've learned my lesson and improved my knowledge, I'm trying to get unbanned.

I used to delete my own questions when they got negative feedback, which I've learned is a bad thing to do. I am trying to improve the deleted questions. But I can't find them in the recently deleted questions, my browser history (I clear it regularly) or using the wayback machine.

What options do I have left to undelete and improve my deleted questions?

**Edit and solution:** Going through the inbox I am able to see most of my deleted questions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where Can One Find their Deleted Questions Or Answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290839/where-can-one-find-their-deleted-questions-or-answers)

Comment: Also [Is it possible to access deleted questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/337014/6045800) and [How to recover deleted Stack Overflow posts (duplicate)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/389876/6045800) with its duplicate target

Comment: The linked posts resolved my issue. Looking through my inbox I could find most of my deleted questions.

Comment: You have the following 1 deleted question: [Q1](//stackoverflow.com/q/66028281).